# Sidebar toggle not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

Sidebar toggle working fine on desktop. When click on toggle button menu hide and after when click on toggle button menu also opening. But not working on mobile device.On mobile when click on toggle button menu not opening.

Here is html code

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">


      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <aside class="main-sidebar">

    <section class="sidebar">



      <ul class="sidebar-menu">


        <li><a href="../admin/index.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Admin</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../workplan/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i><span> Workplan</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../activity/"><i class="fa fa-television" ></i><span> Activities</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../calendar/"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span>Calendar</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../contacts/"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>Contacts</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../venue/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i><span>Venue</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../purchaseOrder/"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i><span>Activity Cost</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../templates/"><i class="fa fa-columns"></i><span>Templates</span></a></li>

        <li><a href="../report/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i><span> Reports</span></a></li>



    </section>

  </aside></body>
```

Here is function for toggle menu

```
 $("a.sidebar-toggle").click(function(){
      $("body").removeClass("hold-transition");
      $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-collapse");
    });
```

Comment: Do provide a fiddle..Also add `css` in your question..

Comment: All right! Do share a fiddle demo including bootstrap...

Comment: please help here if you can . not proper showing on fiddle.

Comment: your CSS would be necessary to help you. But apart from that: do you really want to toggle a class on the `body`?